# How to remove warning from the compiler

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am developing an quiz app .  I  am  getting  following  warning[image]

How    would  i  print  arrayElement correctly?

Comment: First, always post code...not images. Second, questions on SO should have a clear problem statement and question. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask You're trying to pass an array of type `NSArray` to the label's text property which expects a string. Just access the item you want in the array `questionArray[0]` or whatever...depending on what is inside of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is the warning because, your are sending `NSArray` where `NSString` is needed.If you ignore this warning, it ABSOLUTELY WILL lead to a crash

`self.questionLabel.text` requires `NSString`

Change that line to:

```
  self.questionLabel.text=self.question[self.currentQuestionIndex];
```

This thing `self.question[self.currentQuestionIndex]` returns a `NSString` according your code.

You dont need to create a new `NSArray` again.

To print the array elements, you can use NSLog statement.

```
   NSLog(@"array elements are %@",array);
```

Comment: If you ignore this warning, it ABSOLUTELY WILL lead to a crash.

Comment: I want to  display  the  question  on  the   screen  not  on  the  console  panel.   To  display  the  question  i  created  questionLabel  outlet. So  what  would i  do?